# How do I call a method just after each test has been constructed? C#, NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm writing Web UI tests using NUnit + Selenium. I'm using ValueSource to pass a list of browsers into a test method, this creates a copy of that test for each browser in the test runner. Inside the test method, I call another method, passing the browser into it so the relevant browser driver is invoked and the test can be conducted.

The issue I'm having is that I need to call the InvokeDriver(browser) method in every single test case, which duplicates code. All the tests need to call this method, passing through the browser from the ValueSource list. So I need a way to call this method *just after* the test is constructed but without this code repetition. I can't call the method in [SetUp] because that gets run before the test (at which time there is no ValueSource value available to pass into InvokeDriver).

```
namespace CoreSeleniumFramework.Tests
{
    public class HomePageTests : TestBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1([ValueSource("BrowserList")] Browsers browser)
        {
            InvokeDriver(browser);
            // Do testing here
        }
    }
}
```

Test base...

```
namespace CoreSeleniumFramework.Base
{
    public enum TestCategories
    {
        Acceptance, Regression, Sanity
    }

    public enum Browsers
    {
        Chrome, Firefox, Edge
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestBase
    {
        public static TestCategories categoryToTest = TestCategories.Acceptance;

        public static List<Browsers> acceptanceBrowsers = new List<Browsers>() {
            Browsers.Chrome
        };
        public static List<Browsers> regressionBrowsers = new List<Browsers>() {
            Browsers.Firefox
        };
        public static List<Browsers> sanityBrowsers = new List<Browsers>() {
            Browsers.Edge
        };

        public IWebDriver driver;

        public void InvokeDriver(Browsers browser)
        {
            switch (browser)
            {
                case Browsers.Chrome:
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case Browsers.Firefox:
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                case Browsers.Edge:
                    driver = new EdgeDriver();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("InitialiseDriver(): chosen browser not recognised.");
            }
        }

        public static List<Browsers> BrowserList()
        {
            List<Browsers> browserList;

            switch (categoryToTest)
            {
                case TestCategories.Acceptance:
                    browserList = acceptanceBrowsers;
                    break;
                case TestCategories.Regression:
                    browserList = regressionBrowsers;
                    break;
                case TestCategories.Sanity:
                    browserList = sanityBrowsers;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("BrowserList(): no browser list available.");
            }

            return browserList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use `Browsers` anywhere else in the test? Or is it just needed for instantiating `WebDriver`?

You could possibly either create yet another method or change current one to invoke driver after retrieving `browserList` and provide it to test case ie.:

```
   public static IEnumerable<IWebDriver> BrowserListInitialized()
    {
        return BrowserList().Select(browser => InvokeDriver(browser));            
    }
```

Change `InvokeDriver` to static and to return initialized driver:

```
    public static IWebDriver InvokeDriver(Browsers browser)
    {
        switch (browser)
        {
            case Browsers.Chrome:
                return new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case Browsers.Firefox:
                return new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case Browsers.Edge:
                return new EdgeDriver();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("InitialiseDriver(): chosen browser not recognised.");
        }
    }
```

And use it:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1([ValueSource("BrowserListInitialized")] IWebDriver driver)
    {
        //driver already initialized and passed as an argument
        driver.DoStuff();
    }
```

Comment: True champion, thank you :) There is one side effect - in Visual Studio, when you change code or add tests (perhaps both) and then Build, a browser instance is loaded up for every test for every browser in that test's list. This problem doesn't occur if running via a console like NUnit Console Runner.